# .plist writing error on device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, device, file-writing

This snippet of code does work on the iPhone simulator but not on device, although I am looking for a file that has been written on disk in the documents directory

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"notificationScheduled.plist"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filepath];
if (fileExists) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    NSLog(@"%@", array);
    [array addObject:date];
    [array writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
} else {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:date];
    [array writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I get no error, but the first part (if(fileExists) { }) is not called, even when running it a second time. It always does the else part, but on the simulator the if(fileExists) part is called the second time..

Comment: I was able to use your code just fine. How are you verifying that the `if` part is not entered?

Comment: using the debugger I see that that part is not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, instead of

```
NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"notificationScheduled.plist"];
```

Used

```
NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"notificationScheduled.plist"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To save a property list:
this may help u

if not just leave this ,since it may help others

```
NSString * error;
NSData * data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:yourPlist format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
[data writeToFile:pathToYourFile atomically:YES];
```

`yourPlist` must be a kind of `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` object.

To read your property list.

```
NSString * error;
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToYourFile];
yourPlist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
```